# What's the best way to ocr as much text as possible from video game screenshots?

Tags: python, automated-tests, ocr, tesseract, ui-automation

I'm trying to use the [tesseract ocr tool](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) to extract ocr text from video games(I'm pre processing screenshots and passing them to command line tool tsv output and parsing that).

I'd like to use it for test automation not unlike selenium web testing. 
That is I'd like to be able to wait for elements to appear instead of sleeping and clicking on buttons(mostly menus).

To be able to do that I need to be able to consistently find the same button text and find as much text as possible against a range of video games.
For the sake of abstraction I'd prefer the pre processing/tesseract options to be the same for every game.

I can probably add a dictionary of each word encountered in each game but I'd prefer not to.

I've got a setup where I can test a number of different combinations of pre-processing/tesseract options and see the resulting words.

I'm already tried blowing up the screenshot (which is 70-90 dpi) 5x times, and making it greyscale before passing it to tesarect.

***What other techniques can I use to improve the number and accuracy of my results? Which tesseract knobs should I be looking at? Is there any other useful pre-processing I can add?***

P.S. I'm finding that if I enlarge the picture to be twice as long/wide tesseract blows up seemingly because it runs out of memory for the image. Is there a static limit? Can I find it so I can blow up the image near max size? Can I adjust it?

Comment: Maybe you could use something like [object tracking in OpenCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#object-tracking) as one of the pre-processing steps to create higher contrast mask and try OCR on that.

Comment: Python remains very slow for this job (including OpenCV, etc.). If the video card is  got Hook API or the game using the Internet, it is better to review the packages. You'll probably have to use assembly or C.

Comment: another approach: rather than trying to recognize the text in the picture, can't you just try to detect if a sample, hardcoded image is present inside the screenshot?

Comment: What are you working on. Can you provide some description. I would contribute if it's on my interest.

Comment: As with virtually *all* computer vision problems this one is best discussed by providing example images. Otherwise it's really hard to make judgment calls.

Answer (score 10):

### Train your own tessdata

This is by far the most important lesson learned from my experience with tesseract. Out of the box tesseract works really well with recognizing scanned book and newspaper text, but when you try using it with a font that is not similar to standard book and newspaper fonts (like Times New Roman) in my experience accuracy decreases significantly. Training used to be much more difficult, but nowadays [tesstrain.sh](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-%E2%80%93-tesstrain.sh) makes it a cinch. You will have to gather up your video game fonts (or ones that look similar to them at least) and provide them as input to the training script. Even if your fonts are widely different, tesseract will be able to choose the right font for the provided image at runtime with amazing accuracy. Also, I know it's tedious, but it would be beneficial to provide the wordlist of all words encountered in the video games to the training script. Training tesseract with your own fonts and your own wordlist will give you near-perfect accuracy without doing much of anything else.

### Preprocess image to recognize

#### Dont rely on tesseract's layout analysis

If you can, do your own layout analysis and crop the image to the parts containing the text. Teseract has a page segmentation engine built-in but it has to cover such a broad range of use cases that it most likely will not work for your particular needs. Also, in my experience it further helps with accuracy if you separate the image out into single lines of text and use the segmentation mode 7 (Treat the image as a single text line).

#### Bump up x-height of input text

It helps if you increase the x-height of the input text to the same height you used to train tesseract (IIRC this was 70 pixels in my case).

#### Bump up DPI of input text

Tesseract [really likes 300 DPI](https://mazira.com/blog/optimal-image-conversion-settings-tesseract-ocr). Note that changing the DPI of an image is not the same as changing its size. (for example, with ImageMagick you would [use the -density option](https://superuser.com/a/479199/778853) to change an image's DPI).

### Tesseract configuration variables to use

In my experience, tweaking the different "penalty" settings having to do with matching dictionary words had the most impact on improving accuracy. The settings that worked for me:

```
language_model_penalty_non_dict_word      0.975
language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word 0.575
segment_penalty_dict_case_bad             1.3125
segment_penalty_dict_case_ok              1.1
segment_penalty_dict_nonword              10.25
```

But you should obviously do your own tweaking. Also, I found that the x-height settings were very useful at runtime: `textord_min_xheight` and `min_sane_x_ht_pixels`.

---

I am not aware of any memory size limits on tesseract. Are you perhaps using tesseract through a wrapper that has its own limits?

---

*Note: this answer is assuming you're using the latest stable build of tesseract, which would be tesseract 3.05. If you're using tesseract 4.0, doing your own training and segmentation would still apply but the other sections of the answer may be OBE.*

Comment: how do i increase the x height? do I just magnify the image vertically?

Comment: Yes, well not just vertically, blow it up to make it match your training image (like I said I think the training script defaults to 70)

Answer (score 2):

Google cloud offers OCR for videos. So you don't have to take a screenshot. You can just update the entire game videos to GCP and call the API to process them. The API will return timestamp and bounding box for each text in the video. It processes very fast, and the results produced are very dense and consistent. You can see the details in the official docs: https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/text-detection

Comment: Is it important how long one image will stay? I want to take a video from a question and answer site like linkedin skill tests and do not want to take a screenshot from each question. Instead, I want to grab a video while answering the 20 questions, which takes approx. 10 minutes (30 seks each question).

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of reasons you mightn't get an appropriate quality output from `tesseract`. It's important to note that unless you are using a very unusual font or a new language retraining `tesseract` is unlikely to help.

So, look at [`ImproveQuality`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#examples) tool for such tasks as: Rescaling, Binarization, Noise Removal, Rotation/Deskewing, and Border Removal.

For instance, here is a script where you can find color conversion, transformation and plot ops:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from skimage.transform import radon
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray, mean, array, blackman
import numpy
from numpy.fft import rfft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import rms_flat

try:
    # More accurate peak finding from
    # https://gist.github.com/endolith/255291#file-parabolic-py
    from parabolic import parabolic

    def argmax(x):
       return parabolic(x, numpy.argmax(x))[0]

except ImportError:
    from numpy import argmax

filename = 'skew-linedetection.png'

# Load file, converting to grayscale
I = asarray(Image.open(filename).convert('L'))
I = I - mean(I)  # Demean; make the brightness extend above and below zero
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(I)

# Do the radon transform and display the result
sinogram = radon(I)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(sinogram.T, aspect='auto')
plt.gray()

# Find the RMS value of each row and find "busiest" rotation,
# where the transform is lined up perfectly with the alternating dark
# text and white lines
r = array([rms_flat(line) for line in sinogram.transpose()])
rotation = argmax(r)
print('Rotation: {:.2f} degrees'.format(90 - rotation))
plt.axhline(rotation, color='r')

# Plot the busy row
row = sinogram[:, rotation]
N = len(row)
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(row)

# Take spectrum of busy row and find line spacing
window = blackman(N)
spectrum = rfft(row * window)
plt.plot(row * window)
frequency = argmax(abs(spectrum))
line_spacing = N / frequency  # pixels
print('Line spacing: {:.2f} pixels'.format(line_spacing))

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.plot(abs(spectrum))
plt.axvline(frequency, color='r')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Algorithms like noise removal and deskewing help with cleaning up scanned images, but I don't think it helps in OP's situation where the image has digital origins.

Comment: @mnistic Noise in blue channel of video file is sometimes more awful than in scanned images. And letters' skew can be like this: http://benjaminpercy.com/thrill-me-essays-on-fiction/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using deep learning methods and particularly object recognition algorithm to detect the button text su chas in https://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/ ?